# Error while applying manifest on puppet agent

Tags: puppet, devops

I installed the docker module on puppet master with this command:

```
puppet module install garethr-docker --version 5.3.0
```

After that I included it in site.pp file:

```
node 'test02.edureka.com'
{
 include 'docker'
 docker::image 
  { 
  'ubuntu':
  image_tag => 'precise'
  }
}
```

But when I apply it in agent machine, I'm getting error:

[image]

[image]

My Puppet version is 3.8.7.

Comment: It looks like your module requires a more recent version of Puppet (at least v4) than you are running on the server (presumably v3.x).

Comment: At puppet forge it says version 5.3.0 is compatible with puppet >= 3.4.0.  https://forge.puppet.com/garethr/docker/compatibility

Comment: Looking more closely at the error message, it appears that the file with the error is actually in the puppetlabs-apt package that is among your module's dependencies.  But it still appears to me that the nature of the problem is that that module requires a more recent Puppet.  Possibly you can downgrade that module to a version compatible with Puppet 3.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Your comment is the correct answer. Care to convert?

Comment: Ok, @MattSchuchard, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message attributes the problem to file `/etc/modules/puppet/apt/manifests/init.pp`, which belongs to an 'apt' module, presumably 'puppetlabs-apt'.  The nature of the problem revolves around the appearance of the word `Variant` in the module's DSL code.  This is a keyword associated with the datatype system introduced in Puppet 4, but in Puppet 3.x it is an ordinary identifier with no special significance.  This tends to indicate that the problem is that you are running Puppet 3.x on the server (latest at this time is 5.3.3), and the version of puppetlabs-apt that you've installed (v3.0.0) is incompatible.

Indeed, [the docs for puppetlabs-apt v3.0.0](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt/3.0.0/compatibility) show that it requires at least version 4.7.0 of Puppet.  Version 2.4.0 was the last release that claims compatibility with Puppet 3, so you should try downgrading to that.

I am uncertain why the module tool chose v3.0.0 of puppetlabs-apt for you, despite its incompatibility.  You could consider raising this as an issue against Puppet, but inasmuch as Puppet 3 is no longer actively developed, it's probably not worth the effort.  Indeed, it may well be that the issue is already fixed in a more recent version.

Comment: An interesting side note is that the downloaded docker module is deprecated in favor of a newer one: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/docker/changelog#version-100.